# Use qcut pandas for multiple valuable categorizing

Tags: python, validation, csv, pandas

I am trying to use two values from two columns from a dataframe and perform `qcut` categorization.

single value categorizing it quite simple. But two variables as pairs and vs is something I am trying get.

Input:

```
date,startTime,endTime,day,c_count,u_count
2004-01-05,22:00:00,23:00:00,Mon,18944,790
2004-01-05,23:00:00,00:00:00,Mon,17534,750
2004-01-06,00:00:00,01:00:00,Tue,17262,747
2004-01-06,01:00:00,02:00:00,Tue,19072,777
2004-01-06,02:00:00,03:00:00,Tue,18275,785
2004-01-06,03:00:00,04:00:00,Tue,13589,757
2004-01-06,04:00:00,05:00:00,Tue,16053,735
2004-01-06,05:00:00,06:00:00,Tue,11440,636
2004-01-06,06:00:00,07:00:00,Tue,5972,513
2004-01-06,07:00:00,08:00:00,Tue,3424,382
2004-01-06,08:00:00,09:00:00,Tue,2696,303
2004-01-06,09:00:00,10:00:00,Tue,2350,262
2004-01-06,10:00:00,11:00:00,Tue,2309,254
```

Code with pure python but I am trying to do the same in pandas.

```
for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if int(row[1])>(0.80*c_count) and int(row[2])>(0.80*u_count):
            val='highly active'
        elif int(row[1])>=(0.60*c_count) and int(row[2])<=(0.60*u_count):
            val='active'
        elif int(row[1])<=(0.40*c_count) and int(row[2])>=(0.40*u_count):  
            val='event based'
        elif int(row[1])<(0.20*c_count) and int(row[2])<(0.20*u_count):
            val ='situational'
        else:
            val= 'viewers'
```

What I am trying to find is ?

1. `c_count` and `u_count` both
2. Like in the above code `c_count` vs `u_count`

Comment: What is max_user and max_key in this dataframe? Maximum of last two columns?

Comment: @ayhan Yeah they are max of two respective last columns and the required changes are made in the shown code to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Series for each quantile group:

```
q = df[['c_count', 'u_count']].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, np.linspace(0, 1, 6), 
                                                       labels=np.arange(5)))
q
Out: 
   c_count u_count
0        4       4
1        3       3
2        3       2
3        4       4
4        4       4
5        2       3
6        2       2
7        2       2
8        1       1
9        1       1
10       0       0
11       0       0
12       0       0
```

0 is for the first 20%, 1 is for 20%-40% and goes on.

Now the if logic works a little different here. For the else part, first populate the column:

```
df['val'] = 'viewers'
```

Anything we do afterwards will overwrite the values in this column if condition is satisfied. So the operation we do later precedes the previous one. From bottom to top:

```
df.ix[(q['c_count'] < 1) & (q['u_count'] < 1), 'val'] = 'situational'
df.ix[(q['c_count'] < 2) & (q['u_count'] > 1), 'val'] = 'event_based'
df.ix[(q['c_count'] > 2) & (q['u_count'] < 2), 'val'] = 'active'
df.ix[(q['c_count'] > 3) & (q['u_count'] > 3), 'val'] = 'highly active'
```

The first condition checks whether both c_count and u_count are in the first 20%. If so, changes the corresponding rows at 'val' column to situational. The remaining ones work in a similar manner. You might need to adjust comparison operators a little bit (greater vs greater than or equal to).

Comment: Thank you so much but somewhere this is seeming little confusing for me. :( is it possible to make it anymore simpler?  ` df2['cat'] = pd.qcut(df2.c_total, q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1.], labels=['viewers','event based','situational','active','highly active'])` This I have used for single column. Something like this ?

Comment: It is like rolling dice. For a single die, you only have 6 possible outcomes but if you have two dice the number of outcomes will be 36. This will be even higher if you are looking at smaller than or greater than conditions. So one way or another you need to do a mapping that translates your own rules to Python/Pandas. I don't know if you can find something less complicated than this.

Comment: Thank you again .. Any possible suggestions for this one too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025705/timeseries-plots-with-bokeh